# JSON Schema for DateTime Validation in Python - AWS Lambda

Tags: python, validation, datetime, lambda, schema

I currently have a JSON schema that required date time validation.

```
"type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "object",    
      "properties": {
          "activeFrom": {"type": "string", "format": "datetime", "pattern": ********},
      }
...
```

Validation should exist so that

1. Dates are in the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.00-00:00
   Represents (Year-Month-Day"T"Hour:Minute:Second.Milisecond-TimeZoneHour:TimeZoneMinute)
   GMT Time Zone = 00:00
   Example: 2022-11-12T16:32:21.00-00:00
2. Incorrect dates are not acceptable (i.e. 31 days in February, or incorporate leap year)

I have tried many different patterns (******) but can't seem to find one that works.

Appreciate any help and apologies if this questions structure is incorrect, new to SO :)

Comment: the format you have is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), so a possibility to validate could be to parse the string to datetime object with the Python 3.7+ standard lib's [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat). If that fails, it's invalid. But: note that the method also parses e.g. date only strings.

Comment: btw. if you have tried something that doesn't work to solve your problem, it's good to add that to the question to show the readers where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will check dates in the way you're looking for.

First though `pip install python-dateutil`

EDIT: Have changed following comments.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse, ParserError
from datetime import timedelta


def check_date_is_legit(input_date):
    """
    Checks if an input_date is legitimate
    :param input_date: string, date to check.
    :return result: False if the date isn't legit and True if it is.
    """

    try:
        parsed = parse(input_date)
        if parsed.tzname() == 'UTC':
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
    except ParserError:
        result = False

    return result
```

Comment: Ah yeah I missed that. It's actually the same as UTC so editing that above.

Comment: thanks for updating. the thing is, the OP basically wants to verify that the string represents date & time in an ISO 8601 format, so the UTC offset can well be something else than zero - means it does not make much sense to assert UTC in the first place.

Comment: parsing to datetime object with the appropriate [strftime directive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) might be more adequate; see also my comment on the question.